# VB.NET 2010 - Chr() Function of another code page

Tags: vb.net

When I use function Chr(225), I get character "á", because code page of Windows is 1250 (System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage)

Is it possible to use Chr(225), but get character of another code page?

For example code 225 represents in code page DOS-852 character "ß".

I need to convert "á" to "ß".

Is it possible to get character of DOS code page 852?
For example Chr(225) should return "ß".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get an Encoding for a specific code page, 852 in your case:

```
Dim enc = Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(852)
Dim str = enc.GetString(New Byte() {225})
```

Have a look at the [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class in general for conversions between text encodings.

Comment: In my situation I do not need to change encoding, but I would like to read code of character "á" ( Asc("á"); = 225), then change code page (to DOS 852 code page) and use Chr(225) to get character "ß".

Comment: Finally I understood your code. Sorry, I am not so good programmer. This code gives me what I need, "ß":

Dim enc As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ibm852")
MsgBox(enc.GetChars({225}))